# 'Duplicate attribute key' when processing dimension for 1 attribute but not another

Tags: ssas, dimension

I have added a couple of new columns to a dimension in SSAS.

When I process the dimension, I get an error similar to the below:

`A duplicate attribute key has been found when processing`

Now I know what this error means- it is referring to an entry in the `State` field whereby I have `San Jose` and `san jose` (notice the case).

However, I am not sure why this error is not coming up for other fields in the dimension.. for example, the name field has `John` and `john`, yet this does not produce an error.

I think I know how to fix the duplicate attribute key (perhaps setting all values to the same case or change the collation of the dimension), however I am wandering why I am not having this problem with the name attribute?

Comment: It also depends on your how the attributes relate to the key. Do you have attribute relationships defined on the dimension with composite keys?  If not, should you?

Comment: @Lock did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Is the collation of your SQL database case sensitive but the collation of your SSAS server and database and dimension is case insensitive? These collations should match.

As for why it is causing an error on State maybe it hits that error before the name error? Attributes further from the key via attribute relationships must be processed first. Or maybe there are two rows with the same city that point to San Jose with different casing but the same doesn't happen for Name?